# Magento 2 how to refresh/reload shipping-method-item.html

Tags: shipping-methods, ajax, magento2.2.2, livereload

I would like to reload the shipping methods information on a click of button for example. [image]

When the country change it does an ajax to

```
http://magento2/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/d24ce87dd5f5681ce4597740729664d8/estimate-shipping-methods
```

and then reload the Shipping Methods!

How to reload in like when user change the country in the drop down on address form.?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**To reload checkout page shipping methods rates block**

As per your requirement add these dependencies

> 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote','Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
> on define[]

```
var address = quote.shippingAddress();
address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();
rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
```